# Is it called "the ledge/ edge of a flower enclosure"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

In front of houses or buildings people have these structures like the one in the above picture. There is an enclosure and flowers are planted in there.

**What is the edge of that enclosure called in everyday conversation?**

Is it called "**the ledge/edge of a flower enclosure**"?

Answer (score 3):

Its a "window box" (if it is hung outside a window) or a planter.

I've spoken Engish for over 40 years and in all that time I can't ever needed to refer particularly to the "edge" in contrast to what? the side? the contents?

> There's an interesting bug on the window box.
> Where, I can't see it.
> Just there, on the edge.

I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: You'd say **lip**, as I put in my answer.  The exact phrase "lip of the planter" appears hundreds of thousands of times in a google search.

Answer (score 1):

As James K says, the "flower enclosure" is called a **planter** or a **window box**.

The usual term for the edge would be the **lip**, which can be [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lip) as "the edge of a hollow vessel or cavity."  Here's an example of how you'd use the word, from the website of a [company that sells planters](https://www.atlaspots.com/tips-for-perfectly-planting-a-planter/):

> Begin planting in the center of the pot and work outward, and make sure that the soil level stays 1-2 inches below the **lip of the planter**.

Comment: It could also be called the rim. You see this particularly used in "rolled rim" styles, where the flowerpot or window box has an edge that's a little bit thicker and more rounded.